# Wording of refaenu for sick person who is not Jewish

Tags: tefilla, gentiles, choleh-sick

The refaenu bracha in the amida has wording to use for praying for someone who is sick.  That wording ends "among the other ailing of Israel". Is it appropriate to use that wording for a sick person who is not Jewish?

(This question is similar to other questions asked on this forum but the other questions do not ask exactly this.)

Comment: I don't see how "among the other ailing of Israel" could be said after a gentile's name. It doesn't make sense. And the blessing ends רופא חולי עמו ישראל so how would this be on topic for the blessing?

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/949904/rabbi-jonathan-ziring/the-beracha-of-refuah-(1)/

Comment: @DoubleAA Ths lecture seems to be the one to which you meant to link: https://www.yutorah.org/sidebar/lecture.cfm/950912/rabbi-jonathan-ziring/the-beracha-of-refuah-2-/